# libudev vs libsensors for sysfs

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver, sensors, android-sensors

I have a temperature sensor on a Linux machine.
The temperature sensor information is available in sysfs.

I want to get these temperature readings from a C app.

I have been browsing the web for a while, and cannot determine whether I should be using libudev.h OR sensors.h (from lm-sensors libsensors library).

Should I be using libudev.h or sensors.h? Is there a downside to using one over the other?

These are the best links I've found for my needs:

libudev: http://www.signal11.us/oss/udev/

libsensors: http://linux.die.net/man/3/libsensors

The lm-sensors website is down (not sure why!).

Regards,
Mahdi

Comment: Neither, waiting for new hardware!